# Error when using type of inside function that takes type parameter

Tags: swift, generics, typeof

Why is it that when using type(of:) inside a simple function, there are no issue. But once the function changes to take in a generic parameter T, type(of:) spoils itself? Even though there is nothing in the function signature that should affect it.

What is in function2 signature that is making type(of: ) fail?

[image]

Comment: Is it possibly getting confused between the function `type(of:)` and the parameter `type` inside the encompassing function. That would be disappointing coz I have spent an hour on this.

Comment: I think the issue is generic parameters name in second function. You called it 'type' and when you use type(of: ..), compiler tries to use that parameter, not normal type(of:) function.

Comment: Yes that is the exact reason. Also always post code as text and not as an image

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I wanted to show the error too :). But sure will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `type`, Swift thought that you meant the function's *parameter* `type`, but you actually meant the [`type(of:)` function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type).

You can either specify the module name (`Swift`) of the `type(of:)` function to differentiate:

```
Swift.type(of: controller)
```

or rename the parameter to something else:

```
public func function2<T>(t: T.Type, controller: UIViewController) -> Any
                         ^
```